# nested set, how to set left and right value with php&mysql

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

when i search on the internet about nested set, everyone assume i have already left and right values. but i dont have (; i have id, name, parent_id as column. how can i find left and right values?

i guess, i must use recursive alg. but not design it yet.

thanks a lot,
erman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current model is called an adjacency list. In order to get left and right values, you'll need to perform a push down stack algorithm to convert your model to a nested set.

Here's an example: http://data.bangtech.com/sql/nested_set_treeview.htm

You can also search the web for other conversions from adjacency list to nested set.

Hope that helps!